# gradle use variables in parent task that are defined in child

Tags: gradle

I have a multiproject gradle build where I declare a task in the parent build that uses a variable that gets declared in the child projects (the value can change depending on the subproject). However, I get an error during the configuration phase that the variable doesn't exist. My setup looks like

build.gradle (top level)

```
subprojects {
   myTask {
     prop = valueDefinedInChild
   }

}
```

And then

build.gradle (subproject)

```
valueDefinedInChild = 'someValue'
```

Is there a way to do this correctly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a way to do this (`project.evaluationDependsOnChildren()`), but I recommend to only use it as a last resort. Instead, I'd configure the commonalities at the top level, and the differences at the subproject level:

build.gradle (top level):

```
subprojects {
    task myTask { // add task to all subprojects
        // common configuration goes here
    }
}
```

build.gradle (subproject):

```
myTask {
    prop = 'someValue'
}
```

Another way to avoid repeating yourself is to factor out common code into a separate script, and have subprojects include it with `apply from:`. This is a good choice when the logic only applies to selected subprojects, or in cases where it's desirable to avoid coupling between parent project and subprojects (e.g. when using Gradle's new [configuration on demand](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/release-notes#improved-scalability-via-configuration-on-demand) feature).

Comment: Thanks I ended up moving common configuration to the top and subproject specific configuration to the subprojects. Works well.