# gradle use variables in sub project that are defined in child

Tags: gradle

Root project build.gradle

```
    subprojects{
    task setUpEnvironmentDirs()<<{
        file("${distDir}").mkdirs()
//        FileTree tree = fileTree(dir:'../../../pngcommon/config-tokens', include:"*.properties")
        project.tree.each {File currentFile ->
            def fileName = "${currentFile.getName().split("\\.")[0]}"
            def destinationFile = "${distDir}/${fileName}/"
            file("${destinationFile}").mkdirs()
        }
    }
    }
```

Sub project build.gradle

```
copyEnvironmentProperties{
    FileTree tree = fileTree(dir:'../../../pngcommon/config-tokens', include:"*.properties")
}
setUpEnvironmentDirs{
    FileTree tree = fileTree(dir:'../../../pngcommon/config-tokens', include:"*.properties")
}
```

The file tree that is commented out in the root project is the variable I am attempting to move to the sub project because the directory path will be different in each sub project.  I saw a similar post and set mine up similarly, but I keep getting an error.

[gradle use variables in parent task that are defined in child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656389/gradle-use-variables-in-parent-task-that-are-defined-in-child)

Error:

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'services'.

  > Could not find property 'tree' on project ':service'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to comment in the code that declares the local variable, and use `tree.each` instead of `project.tree.each`. The relative paths will be resolved correctly.

Comment: Sorry I had forgotten I put that in there. I removed it and got the error. * What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'services'.
> Could not find property 'tree' on project ':service'.

Comment: As I already said, you have to change `project.tree.each` to `tree.each`. And you *do* need to keep the `FileTree tree = ...` line.

Comment: Correct. I changed project.tree =  to tree = and still received the error. that I posted in the previous comment.

Comment: Probably you didn't comment in the `FileTree tree =` line. There isn't really another explanation.

Comment: Thanks I got it. Tree needs to be declared in the root project then initialized in the sub project.