# gradle uploadArchives for multiple subproject with different maven group and version

Tags: gradle

I have the following build.gradle and it works for the individual sub project (or all of them if I copy paste it):

```
def group = 'com.my.pgk'
def artifact = project.name
def version = '1.0.0'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            def finalPath = 'file://' + LocalMavenRepoPath.toString()
            println group
            println finalPath
            repository url: finalPath
            pom.groupId = group
            pom.artifactId = artifact
            pom.version = version
            pom.packaging = 'jar'
        }
    }
}

jar {
    archiveName = artifact + "-" + version + ".jar"
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    archiveName = artifact + "-v" + version + "-src.jar"
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    archiveName = artifact + "-v" + version + "-doc.jar"
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
    archives javadocJar
}
```

It is doing exactly what I want it to...

Trying to move this to the root project build.gradle doesn't because the variables defined in the subprojects are not updated when uploadArchives is called.

How can I work around this?

Comment: are you putting uploadArchives in a subProjects section when moving it to root build.gradle?

Answer (score 1):

You need the subprojects to be configured first so that gradle is aware of the subproject variables before the root build.gradle is configured. You can force a bottom-up configuration by using:

```
evaluationDependsOnChildren()
```

Comment: Where exactly should I place it? Also I've read on [another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656389/gradle-use-variables-in-parent-task-that-are-defined-in-child) that it is preferable to use this as a last resort, so is there another way?

Comment: Directly into your root build.gradle (At the zero indent level). Gradle default evaluation order is to evaluate root project first. I agree that reversing the order is less than ideal. It can potentially break other parts of your script that need root to be evaluated first - but I haven't seen major issues in practice with using evaluationDependsOnChildren.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you move to the newer 'maven-publish' plugin instead of the `maven` plugin - it handles publications configuration a bit better.

Comment: The alternate way is to move all common config such as groupID and version to root build.gradle, and use defaults like project name for moduleID. This way your uploadArchives doesn't complain about missing variables while evaluating root build.gradle first.

Answer (score 0):

In a project with a single root and two subprojects, you can create a common gradle script in the root project and apply it to each of the subprojects.

Root Project:
build.gradle

```
//nothing to see here
```

Root Project: common.gradle

```
if (!project.hasProperty("commonVar")) {
    ext.commonVar = "unset"
}


task printCommonVar() {
    println commonVar
}
```

Root Project: settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'GradleGroupProject'

// Find the directories containing a "build.gradle" file in the root directory
// of the project. That is, every directory containing a "build.gradle" will
// be automatically the subproject of this project.

def subDirs = rootDir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        if (!file.isDirectory()) {
            return false
        }
        if (file.name == 'buildSrc') {
            return false
        }
        return new File(file, 'build.gradle').isFile()
    }
});

subDirs.each { File dir ->
    include dir.name
}
```

Subproject 1: build.gradle

```
ext.commonVar = "subproject1"
apply from: rootProject.file('common.gradle')
```

Subproject 2: build.gradle

```
ext.commonVar = "subproject2"
apply from: rootProject.file('common.gradle')
```

The ordering between `ext.commonVar = "subproject2"` and `apply from: rootProject.file('common.gradle')` is important.